# How to download a large file without using the automatic chunking that URLSessionDownloadTask uses

Tags: ios, macos, networking

Normally I'd use `URLSessionDownloadTask` when downloading a file that I want saved to disk, however I have realized that this automatically divides up the download into chunks and makes numerous HTTP requests until it completes. I am talking to an unconventional web server that does not support chunking because it only allows a single connection to start downloading a file. After that request finishes the file is no longer available, thus any chunk requests after the first one fail. These files can be anywhere from a few KB to GB, so whatever I do needs to not try keeping the whole file in memory as it arrives. I don't see any way to disable chunking on a `URLSessionDownloadTask`, my Android counterpart switched to using "streaming" and its now working fine for him. It looks like I may need to use `URLSessionStreamTask` and manually handle all the communication, but I'm not really sure.

When I do a download using `URLSessionDownloadTask` the response headers are:

`elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("Content-Type")
      - value : "Content-Type"
    - value : application/octet-stream
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("Connection")
      - value : "Connection"
    - value : keep-alive
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("Content-Length")
      - value : "Content-Length"
    - value : 85204043
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("Date")
      - value : "Date"
    - value : Fri, 20 Apr 2018 09:12:57 GMT
  ▿ 4 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("Server")
      - value : "Server"
    - value : nginx/1.10.3
  ▿ 5 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("Etag")
      - value : "Etag"
    - value : "852040431517695334"`

I just learned about[Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) and I'm trying to set it to `Identity` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Does your web server provide `Content-Length` header? Chunked transfer encoding is used when there's no information about data size so it is transferred in chunks.

Comment: @DanKarbayev yes it does appear to be returning `Content-Length`, doing more testing to see if it does 100% of the time, or if sometimes it doesn't. That might explain why transfers work fine using `URLSessionDownloadTask` some of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a `Transfer-Encoding = identity` fixes it and causes the server/app to never chunk.